# Do the elements of a sequence converging to a point in the intrinsic core of a convex cone belong to the intrinsic core of the set eventually?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a general Banach space and let $C\subset X$ be a convex cone.
Consider a sequence $x_n$ in the affine hull of $C$ such that $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in icr(C)$, where $icr(C)$
denotes the intrinsic core of $C,$ i.e., the core of $C$ relative to the affine hull of $C$.\

Is it true that $x_n\in icr(C)$ for $n$ large enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since both $x_n$ and $x$ belong to the affine hull, you can restate your problem in the normed space "affine hull of $C$". And then, $\mathrm{icr}(C)$ is open in that space.